# WPF Animation that bends and follows some path geometry

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

Okay, so I'm working on a loading screen and I want to flare it up a bit.

Basically what I am trying to do is animate an object *along* path geometry data...I emphasize 'along' because keeping a fixed object along the path on a tangent is not what I would like to do

This is the best representation of what I am trying to do:

[image]

I can use a matrix transform to send this border element along the path but it winds up coming out as a tangential animation that moves and rotates with the path, but does not bend to fit the shape of the path...Here is an example of that:

```
<Border Background="Black" BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="20" Height="20">
<Border.RenderTransform>
    <MatrixTransform x:Name="MatrixT">
        <MatrixTransform.Matrix>
            <Matrix/>
        </MatrixTransform.Matrix>
    </MatrixTransform>
</Border.RenderTransform>
<Border.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <MatrixAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="MatrixT" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Matrix" DoesRotateWithTangent="True" Duration="0:0:5" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M201.1,50.501C201.1,78.138,178.737,100.501,151.1,100.501L150.799,100.501C123.162,100.501,114.933,77.834,100.8,50.501L100.8,50.5C86.666,23.167,78.437,0.5,50.8,0.5L50.5,0.5C22.863,0.5,0.500000000000014,22.863,0.500000000000014,50.5L0.500000000000014,50.501C0.500000000000014,78.138,22.863,100.501,50.5,100.501L50.8,100.501C78.437,100.501,86.666,77.834,100.8,50.501L100.8,50.5C114.933,23.167,123.162,0.5,150.799,0.5L151.1,0.5C178.736,0.5,201.1,22.863,201.1,50.501L201.1,50.501z" PresentationOptions:Freeze="True"/>
                    </MatrixAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                </MatrixAnimationUsingPath>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Border.Triggers>
```

I have come up with an alternative solution that looks really sharp, but I wanted to pitch this question out to the community to see if they have any ideas on how to accomplish this task (or if it is even possible)...I have done some extensive googling on the matter and have come up with nothing on how to accomplish this in an effective means.

The requirements:

1. It must follow (or 'bend along') the path
2. It must be able to scale in size without breaking the animation (many of the stroke animation representations I have seen of this can only operate at one size without re-configuring the animation properties)...a viewbox is perfectly acceptable to accomplish this

If the shape can be tapered and faded out on the trailing side that would be an even bigger plus (see the image above), but that might be more than is possible

EDIT:
To clarify what I mean by 'bend'...I mean figure B below...figure A is the standard that I have traditionally seen:

[image]

Comment: have you tried the PathListbox http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/

Comment: hmmm...thats an interesting control I hadn't seen yet, I actually have a few other uses for that...but it ultimately still doesn't allow for the object to bend/curve along the path, just tangentially rotate along it

Comment: this actually do what you are looking for just do a little google.

Comment: I still can't seem to find anything related to what I'm looking for with that...see the second picture I just added to the question...the PathListBox appears to allow you to place an array of display elements along a path, but it does not warp the appearance of the elements to bend along the path (outside of rotation/translate/scale)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Morphing your shape to a path would be very difficult in WPF.  However there is a close approximation possible by animating two separate paths, and also animating two clipping regions at the same time.

Given below is XAML for an approximation of what you want.  If you look carefully at the crossing point of the infinity symbol, you will notice a slight discontinuity in the smoothness of the shading during transition.  This is because I was a little bit arbitrary in my setting of the Start, End, and Offset points for the `LinearGradientBrush` objects.  A little work on those will smooth out that transition.  You could even choose to animate the properties on the brushes to help with that.

```
<Window x:Class="AnimationTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Background="#FF486CBF">
  <Viewbox>
    <Grid>
      <Canvas Width="50" Height="50"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Canvas.Clip>
          <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,55">
            <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
              <TranslateTransform x:Name="_clip1"/>
            </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
          </RectangleGeometry>
        </Canvas.Clip>
        <Path StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
              StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
              StrokeThickness="10"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.8571"
              Data="M 5,25 c 0,-25 40,-25 40,0">
          <Path.Stroke>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
              <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.7"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
          </Path.Stroke>
          <Path.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="_rot1" />
          </Path.RenderTransform>
          <Path.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation From="360" To="0"
                                   Duration="0:0:3"
                                   RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="_rot1"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"/>
                  <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_clip1"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                         RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="25"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.8" Value="55"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4.5" Value="-30"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5.8" Value="0"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="0"/>
                  </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
          </Path.Triggers>
        </Path>
      </Canvas>

      <Canvas Width="50" Height="50"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Margin="40,0,0,0">
        <Canvas.Clip>
          <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,50,55">
            <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
              <TranslateTransform x:Name="_clip2"/>
            </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
          </RectangleGeometry>
        </Canvas.Clip>
        <Path StrokeStartLineCap="Round"
              StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
              StrokeThickness="10"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.8571"
              Data="M 5,25 c 0,-25 40,-25 40,0">
          <Path.Stroke>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,0">
              <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0.7"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
          </Path.Stroke>
          <Path.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="_rot2" />
          </Path.RenderTransform>
          <Path.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
              <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360"
                         Duration="0:0:3"
                         RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="_rot2"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"/>
                  <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="_clip2"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                         RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="55"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="-30"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.8" Value="0"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4.5" Value="25"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5.8" Value="55"/>
                    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="55"/>
                  </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
          </Path.Triggers>
        </Path>
      </Canvas>
    </Grid>
  </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

An important point to note is that the clipping regions need to be applied to the `Canvas` objects.  If they are applied to the `Path` objects, like you would normally do for an image, the clipping region then gets rotated along with the `Path` by the `RenderTrasform`.  Not the desired effect.

Comment: CLIPPING!  a-HA!  That's the piece I was missing entirely...I kind of figured that I would need to fake the animation a tad, but my qualms with that were always due to the inability to make the morphed edges smooth...clipping very much is a solution for that.  +1 kudos for the working code

Comment: Has WPF changed? I'm getting an error for `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">` VS claims it's an invalid property for `RoutedEvent`.

Comment: @JoshVarty I just reloaded this old project and it ran fine.  I'm still using Visual Studio 2012 Professional.  It's running in the .NET 4.0 framework.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using VS 2015. Perhaps things are changing. A few MSDN WPF pages have been pulled down in the last week too. I'll create a new question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just put a lot of circles on the path and animate their diameters.

Comment: Technically, this is an answer, but it's not really ideal...there has to be a better way to accomplish this task...plus, unless you scale it super small you would have to have a LOT of circles in place to not see that it's not a smooth line

Comment: It depends on what you consider ideal and on how big the animation has to be.It might be too complicated to create a 'perfect' solution and fully acceptable to fake it.

Comment: Agreed, my current solution is using a set of 7 or 8 circles that follow the path and trail each other (with spaces between each other), somewhat like your solution...what I'm looking for though is a means of morphing the object using path geometry, which is useful for more than just animation...I have a pretty good feeling that this isn't possible out of the box however, so if I don't get any solutions to this in the next few days or so I'll take this as an answer to the question

Comment: Correct. "Out of the box" is not available. Following a path is possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd263097.aspx morphing is a different beast: what happens when a segment is on a very sharp edge?

Comment: Yea there are definitely challenges with morphing, but it would still be useful to have that ability...sharp edges are an issue, but that is more-so an issue of improper usage of the feature than an imposibility...calculating the vertices of a spline along a sharp edge's sampled points and rendering it would be no different than rendering it along a smooth edge's sampled points (it would still require the exact same mathematical formula), but the end result would probably be undesired

Comment: really when I think about it more, it ultimately would come down to animating the points of a spline along a path (though that is much easier said than done...)  I might look into that some more when I get some more free time

Comment: Oh yes, it is definitely possible and a very nice math problem too :) but from a graphic designer's point of view it can be pretty hard to get it right and to tweak it.